# Receiving online payments without disclosing my name and home address?

Tags: online-payment, paypal, privacy

Is there a payment gateway or something that keeps your name/identity private and not seen that takes credit cards? Does PayPal work, or does it show your name and home address?

I would ONLY like my business name to be shown or business address NOT my personal information.

Thanks.

Comment: So open a business account, what's the problem?

Answer (score 5):

- Set up a business account (an LLC, for example).
- Buy a post office box for your business.
- If you're running a website, get private registration for your domain.

That should obscure your name and home address fairly well.

Answer (score 0):

There are several different actors in the system of online payment:
There are: Card Holder --> Merchant  --> Payment-gateway --> Card Scheme (Visa/MasterCard) --> Issuer  
The name and your identification details are stored in your issuer- the company who issued your credit card. 
All the other actors are not aware of your name and you can keep it this way.
The mandatory fields that you must provide during payment of transaction in order to authorize the transaction are:

- Credit-card-number
- expiration-date
- CVV number

Besides, refer to [this discussion](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/44745/credit-card-with-no-card-holder-names-on-it?rq=1) in a similar question to yours, that might have the answer to what you are looking for.