# Credit card with no card holder names on it

Tags: credit-card, online-payment, privacy

### I am interested in creating a credit/debit card for online use which in no way references my real names and etc.

I need to use, for say, pay some website hosting and not expose my credit card printed name on it. I looked around in Virtual Credit Cards but it seems the only difference in them is that you actually do not have a plastic card (but you still have names printed on it)

I can remember there was some online service (it was a startup which generated a lo of drama) which offered you to input your credit card details there and they would mask your identity on websites which you do purchases.

### Is having such card possible at all?

Countries of interest are USA and European countries.

P.S: I require this for privacy concerns not for criminal use, so please stop with those questions.

Comment: Could you not start a business (as sole prop), and get a card in the business name?   I work as an independent contractor, and regularly get offers for business credit cards.

Answer (score 5):

[Abine](https://www.abine.com/) has a product for iOS and Android (and desktop), now called called Blur, that provides credit card masking (alias credit card numbers), along with other privacy services. It's subscription-based. I've used it successfully for a number of transactions over the past year or so. To the merchant, you supply any name, Abine's address, and the specific masked credit card number and code. You can create any number of masked cards with different credit amounts, and the charges show up on your real card statement as "Abine, Inc.".

Comment: Is it reliable? Because I am suspicious so far.

Comment: Reliable in what way? I haven't had any transactions denied, and since the transactions I've used it for don't require a shipping address, I didn't provide any of my actual personal information to these merchants. I believe it is US only for now though.

Answer (score 3):

Does not a reloadable card purchased from a store meet your requirements?

Note, however, that my memory is that if you buy such a card in the US it can't be used outside the US--to keep it from being used to take money out of the country.

Comment: OK, this was helpful. I found a bank in my country which offers a pre-paid VISA "Gift Card" which I can register in the name of the gift-receiver or with no name at all. I am currently investigating if it work with PayPal.

Comment: What were your findings? I see there are some consumer protection downsides: https://www.creditcards.com/credit-card-news/6-things-know-reloadable-prepaid_cards-1271.php

Answer (score 2):

See what your current card requires for additional cards.

When my daughter turned 16, and I ordered a card for her, I realized the issuer didn't ask for her social security number, only a name and address. 
That's when I also ordered a card with my pseudonym. Which I believe is what you're looking for.

I realize that you prefer no name at all, but any online site where you place an order will require you to fill in that name field .